# Optimal way to filter a pandas data frame column by predicate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Pandas and I was searching for a way to filter a data frame column by arbitrary unary predicate. So far I've found the following works:

```
def filterDataFrameColByPred(dataFrame, columnName,predicate):
    return dataFrame[dataFrame[columnName].apply(predicate)]
```

I am not too familiar with Pandas internals and was wondering if there was a more optimal way to filter by arbitrary predicate?  My goal is to keep the predicate general in order to reuse this function on mid-to-small sized data frames.

Edit: Optimal with respect to query time.

Comment: it's really hard to advise anything at this level of generality. In many cases columnwise operations are more effective (e.g. `df.loc[df['col'] % 2]` to get odd numbers), but it requires some level of specificity.